# Is there an intuitive understanding of what a walsh coefficient is?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I am working with Walsh coefficients.

I know the intuitive understanding is almost that that they are the degree of connectivity, but it is there a better way of thinking about it? What is the definition of a Walsh coefficient besides "What you get when you take the Walsh transform".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my intuitive perspective. Except for the first coefficient, which indicates the constant bias of the entire input, the coefficients represent $2^n-1$ different perspectives on the input. More specifically, they represent comparisons between the sum of one half of the input with the sum of other half. Coefficients which are zero represent perspectives of equal sums. Coefficients with the largest absolute magnitude indicate perspectives where the the difference of the sums is the greatest - *features* if you will.